# How do detect where a user tapped on my screen, with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to know the x/y coordinates of where a tap occurred on my screen. I found the GestureDetector, but it doesn't seem to tell me where exactly the tap took place.

Here's my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('tapped!')
    );
  }
}
```

Which does register a tap... but how do I found out *where* the tap started from?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Observe onTapDown and onTapUp, they provide more details for you to work with.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('tapped!'),
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTapDown(details),
      onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) => _onTapUp(details),
    );
  }

  _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
    // or user the local position method to get the offset
    print(details.localPosition);
    print("tap down " + x.toString() + ", " + y.toString());
  }

  _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
    // or user the local position method to get the offset
    print(details.localPosition);
    print("tap up " + x.toString() + ", " + y.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: onTap is meant for the common case where you don't care about the position. If the onTap handler took an argument, everyone would have an ignored argument in their onTap handlers, which adds complexity and cognitive overhead. onTapDown and onTapUp are for the edge cases where you want to do something more fancy than just detect a touch.

Comment: Don't forget that you can convert the position to local coordinates with context.findRenderObject().globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

Comment: But the cognitive overhead is increased even more by having 8 tap handlers on a gesture detector. I doubt that extra param would make much difference.

Comment: @Brandon what about single tap coordinate ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `onTapDown` property in this way:

```
  onTapDown: (details) {
    var position = details.globalPosition;
    print(position.dx);
    print(position.dy);             
  }
```